# Unattented conversion of PowerPoint presentations to video files

Tags: windows, video, conversion, microsoft-powerpoint

I want to be able to convert ppt to video files automatically, without user interaction on Windows. Like `convert_ppt_to_video qqq.pptx --screen-size 1024x768 -o qqq.mkv`.

How it's better to attain this? What programs should I use?

Answer (score 0):

You should just set the slides to automatically progress to the next slide after a given amount of time.  Then, if you have a hypercam (screenshot-like video recorder), record the slideshow.  Then crop the start and finish times to your desired times.

Comment: OK. Now thinking how to make all this unattended and in background.

Comment: What exactly are you going to use the presentation/video for?

Comment: Playing it on remote GNU/Linux system without user interaction.

Comment: Then my solution should work, because you just want a video that plays without anybody having to do anything, right?

Comment: Yes. /* Won't accept this answer because of info about which programs are best for it hasn't been presented */

Comment: Okay gotcha.  I have contacted some friends who have had similar problems.  I am waiting for them to get back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it can be done with PowerPoint for showing the presentation, RDP client for setting the screen resolution and Screen Capture Recorder + VLC to record it to file.

```
vlc.exe  -I dummy dshow://screen-capture-recorder --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theora,vb=1500}:standard{access=file,mux=ogg,dst="d:/home/fff.ogg"}'
```